# Instagram API, OAuth, and 404

Tags: jquery, oauth, instagram, instagram-api

I am using a jQuery plugin called [Pongstgrm](http://pongstr.github.io/pongstagr.am/). After crawling through the set up and code to no avail, I thought it might be a problem with the access ID/token, so I generated a new access token and updated it in the code, however I am getting the following error in the browser console:

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/xxx/media/recent?count=12&access_token=xxx.xxx.xxx&callback=jQueryxxx_xxx

Here's the code I'm using:

```js
$('#insta').pongstgrm({
  accessId:'00000000000000000000000000000000',
  accessToken:'00000000000000000.00000000000000000000000000000000',
  show: 'recent',
  column: "col-xs-6 col-sm-3 col-md-2 col-lg-2",
  count:12,
  effects: null,
  likes: false,
  comments:false,
  timestamp: false,
  buttontext: ' + ' 
});
```

```html
<div id="insta"></div>
```

I read something about requests to the API not being permitted without the website of origin didn't own a valid SSL certificate, but I've seen so many Worpdress themes use Instagram feeds that I can't imagine this to be a problem. Any ideas?

EDIT 1: The creator of the plugin said I might have to re-register the app and generate a new access token. So, I created a new 'client' in Instagram API, generated a new access token, but it still didn't work. Do I have to actually push the app through the approval process and provide my own privacy policy just to be able to use a simple plugin that someone else made on my own website?! Surely not. I also wasn't sure where to get the 'accessID' from, as it isn't mentioned at all in the developer documentation.

EDIT 2: The plugin creator said that he hasn't got time to read the new API documentation and so I have abandoned ever getting this to work and installed another plugin called 'InstaMax'.

Comment: are u passing user-id in URL, and not username ?

Comment: Yes, I am using the correct accessID and accessToken.

Comment: https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/xxx/media/recent - what are u replacing xxx with?, it should be user-id (number), not username, if u have username , u get 404

Comment: That link is generated using my accessID and accessToken. I did not use my username at any point.

Comment: what is the url you are making api call, api.instagram.com/v1/users/xxx/media/recent, what is xxx???